# Can an EFS filesystem mount just go away at random?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

We have an EFS and an EC2 that mounts it. Inside the EC2 we have a volume being mounted by Docker running a Lumen app, so now my app has access to the EFS. I know that if this mount does not happen, that our application will write all files to Lumen's local space, which gets destroyed if we destroy the Docker instance. We have code to ensure that the initial mount, when we spin up Elastic Beanstalk, happens, and that we have a writeable mounted filesystem.

What we were wondering is how common is it for these mounts to just disappear after a successful mount(this can be after days, month etc), and what would be the best way to check whether the mounting is still active?

My current thought is to have a file on the EFS and see intermittently whether my application can read it. But this plan is based on the assumption that this mounted volume can go away for some reason.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed without actual addressing the fact that, yes sometimes the EFS mount disappears, and it is a problem for production systems. I'm currently trying to figure out why the EFS mount will randomly disappear. Re-mounting it works, mount at boot is fine, it's just that sometimes the mount does not persist as you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as "availability" of AWS EFS is concerned it is quite reliable. From the pages of documentation

> every EFS file system object (such as directory, file, and link) is
> redundantly stored across multiple AZs for file systems using Standard
> storage classes.

There is lifecycle feature of AWS EFS which can move the files between different types of EFS (Standard to One Zone etc).

For durability, it provides 11 9s of durability (same as s3) over a 1 year period which is quite good for general systems.

So AWS EFS can't be unmounted by itself. At least it should not happen at all. Though you can change the tier based on access using lifecycle events.

Lifecycle
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/lifecycle-management-efs.html

FAQs which talks about availability and durability: https://aws.amazon.com/efs/faq/